# MySQL procedure loop error

Tags: mysql, sql

When running my query I am getting this:

**error:**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

**SQL:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertPromos;
CREATE PROCEDURE insertPromos()
BEGIN
  DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
  insertPromosLoop : LOOP

  IF (int_val = 501) THEN
    LEAVE insertPromosLoop;
  END IF;
    INSERT INTO `promo_code` (`code`, `valid_from` ,`valid_to` , `free_period`)VALUES (CONCAT('PROMO', int_val),  '2013-10-10',  '2013-11-10',  'P1M');
    SET int_val = int_val +1;
  END LOOP; 
END;
CALL insertPromos();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a new delimiter

```
delimiter |

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertPromos |

CREATE PROCEDURE insertPromos()
BEGIN
  DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
  insertPromosLoop : LOOP

  IF (int_val = 501) THEN
    LEAVE insertPromosLoop;
  END IF;
    INSERT INTO `promo_code` (`code`, `valid_from` ,`valid_to` , `free_period`)VALUES (CONCAT('PROMO', int_val),  '2013-10-10',  '2013-11-10',  'P1M');
    SET int_val = int_val +1;
  END LOOP; 
END
|

delimiter ;

CALL insertPromos();
```

Otherwise the procedure definition would end at the first `;` which would not be correct.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. Thanks a lot. First time using procedures.